# Как создать макрос на Vba(в word) который выводит все целые числа(с помощью регулярных выражений) из текущего документа?

Tags: vba, ms-word, макросы

Допустим такой текст
Dsad
Л
test
213
4
54.2
и должно вывести в MsgBox: 213 и 4
Я написал вот этот код, но ничего не работает(m ставил и String и Integer, все равно не работает). Нужно обязательно использовать регулярные выражения

```
Option Explicit

Sub d()
Dim s As String
s = ThisDocument.Range.Text
isdigit (s) 
End Sub

Sub isdigit(x As String)

Dim s As RegExp, z As Match
Dim m As Integer
    
Set s = New RegExp
s.Global = True
s.IgnoreCase = True
s.Pattern = "\d+"
For Each z In s.Execute(x)
    m = m + z.Value + vbCrLf
Next
    
MsgBox m
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы игнорировать дробные числа, можно, например использовать regex вида

> `(?<!\.)\d+\b(?!\.\d)`

с негативными просмотрами вперед и назад [демо](https://regex101.com/r/kqnddw/1), однако "VBScript.RegExp" таким тонкостям не обучен и выдает ошибку.
Поэтому рабочий вариант - выбирать все дробные и недробные числа, потом фильтровать.

```
Sub ExtractNNumbers()
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With RegEx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "\d+\.?\d*"
    End With
    Set res = RegEx.Execute(ActiveDocument.Range.Text)
    For Each s In res
        If InStr(s, ".") = 0 Then
            Debug.Print s
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Тестовый пример

```
Dsad
Л test 213 4 54.2 (100)
255,14.2245
100 200.7878 300 444.
```

Результат

```
213
4
100
255
100
300
```

Comment: А не работает! И почему было бы не проверить на данных из вопроса? Там выдаёт 213 4 54 2, т. е. нецелое число 54.2 выдаётся как два целых. Надо подумать над тем, чем ограничена запись числа с разных сторон, какой десятичный разделитель используется, а ещё, возможно, и разделитель разрядов. А ещё буква E может стоять (экспоненциальная форма представления), и там могут быть записаны как целые, так и нецелые числа. Автору вопроса нужно всё это определить, дополнив вопрос.

Comment: Скорее всего придётся выбрать все числа, а потом проверить, какие из них целые.

Comment: С паттерном ^\d+$ у меня всё работает.